# I am trying to convert json file containing multiple nested arrays to csv file using powershell

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, csv

I am trying to convert json file to csv file using Powershell. The json file that I am trying to convert has multiple nested arrays. I want to expand them all. Following is the file structure and the code I am working with:

This is a snapshot of my feed.json file:

```
{  
    "result": {  
    "problems": [  
      {  
        "id": "AHR157689",  
        "displayName": "YOCETJE",  
        "impact": "STRUCTURE",  
        "status": "OPEN",  
        "tagsOfEntities": [],  
        "ranked": [  
          {  
            "entityId": "843675746378564876",  
            "entityName": "HGFUTGYJDH",  
            "severityLevel": "8957685N8Y",  
          }  
        ],  
        "affectedCounts": {  
          "INFRA": 1,  
          "STRUCTURE": 0,  
          "APPLICATION": 0,   
        },  
        "recoveredCounts": {  
          "INFRA": 0,  
          "STRUCTURE": 0,  
          "APPLICATION": 0,  
        },  
        "RootCause": true  
      }  
]  
}  
}
```

And below is the code I am working with:

```
Get-Content C:\Documents\feed.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -Expand result | Select -Expand problems | Select * -Expand tagsOfEntities | Select * -Expand ranked | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File C:\Documents\output.csv
```

The above code is giving the correct output csv file but it runs for 2 hours. Am I doing something wrong?

This is the output in output.csv fil. This all data comes in one cell.

CONTEXTLESS,"1","Application","843675746378564876","843675746378564876","8957685N8Y","AHR157689","YOCETJE","STRUCTURE","OPEN","@{"INFRA": 1; "STRUCTURE": 0,"APPLICATION": 0}","@{"INFRA": 0;"STRUCTURE": 0;"APPLICATION": 0}","true"

Comment: Try specifying the `-Depth` parameter to [ConvertFrom-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6).

Comment: Why does your `json` ***input*** file have a `.csv` extension?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible. A sample input and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: @RichMoss I tried it but I am getting this error: 
ConvertTo-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Depth'.
At line:4 char:15
+ ConvertTo-Csv -Depth 3 |
+               ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToCsvCommand

Comment: Please [edit] your question to contain additional/corrected information, don't put that into comments. Add a more detailed example of your `feed.json`

Comment: You put the `-Depth` parameter in the wrong place. `Get-Content C:\Downloads\feed.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 5 |
    Select -Expand results | Select -Expand problem | ConvertTo-Csv |
    Out-File C:\Downloads\output.csv `

Comment: @RichMoss I tried this, but I am still getting the same error.   ConvertFrom-Json : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Depth'.
At line:2 char:18
+ ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 5 |
+                  ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Comment: @RichMoss I also tried ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4 | ConvertFrom-Json

Answer (score 0):

There a two problems with your input JSON.

1. There are commas with nothing after, causing it to fail parsing with 'invalid JSON primitive' errors.
2. There was a curly bracket near the end that should have been a square bracket.

Also, the Powershell is selecting `results` but the JSON has `result`. Similarly, it's selecting `problem` but the JSON has `problems`.

Here's an example that corrects the JSON and a few other issues:

```
@"
{  
"result": {  
"problems": [  
  {  
    "id": "AHR157689",  
    "displayName": "YOCETJE",  
    "impact": "STRUCTURE",  
    "status": "OPEN",  
    "tagsOfEntities": [],  
    "ranked": [  
      {  
        "entityId": "843675746378564876",  
        "entityName": "HGFUTGYJDH",  
        "severityLevel": "8957685N8Y"  
      }  
    ],  
    "affectedCounts": {  
      "INFRA": 1,  
      "STRUCTURE": 0,  
      "APPLICATION": 0   
    },  
    "recoveredCounts": {  
      "INFRA": 0,  
      "STRUCTURE": 0,  
      "APPLICATION": 0  
    },  
    "RootCause": true  
  }  
  ]  
  }  
} 
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json | Select -Expand result | Select -Expand problems | 
Select * -Expand ranked | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File .\output.csv
```

Comment: It's working, but only ranked is getting expanded, tagsofEntities is not. I tried the below code but it's also not working. Get-Content C:\Documents\feed.json -Raw | 
ConvertFrom-Json | 
Select -Expand result | 
Select -Expand problems |
Select *  -Expand tagsOfEntities | 
Select * -Expand ranked |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | 
Out-File C:\Documents\output.csv

Comment: `Select-Object` can only [expand a single property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6#parameters). Chaining the `Select ... -Expand` commands together with a pipeline works to drill down into the hierarchy, but not to flatten an object. You can manually flatten the object hierarchy with syntax like this: `Select id, displayName, status, @{N='affectedCounts_INFRA'; E={$_.affectedCounts.INFRA}},@{N='recoveredCounts_INFRA'; E={$_.recoveredCounts.INFRA}}`

Comment: It's giving error Select : The property cannot be processed because the property "status" already exists ... for all the properties and it is running for more than 1 hr.

Comment: Try commenting this out  `#| ConvertTo-Csv ...` and experiment with changing the parameters in your `Select ` command until you get the desired output. If you get stuck, please update the question with your current code.